# CKEditor plugin not in plugins folder

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When I used CKBuilder to build my editor I have added the `uploadImage` plugin and it shows in the 'Selected Plugins' list. But when I build CKEditor and download the `zip` file, the `uploadImage` folder (and its depencies) is not in the `plugins` folder. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you used CKBuilder to add the plugin, everything should be OK - CKBuilder creates an optimized, production-ready CKEditor distribution, with all dependencies resolved, and **with all `plugin.js` files merged into the `ckeditor.js` file** for better performance.

If you download the plugin `zip` file manually, you need to (1) manually resolve all plugin dependencies and (2) manually add the additional plugins to your editor configuration. Plus the performance gets a hit because you will need to be loading additional plugin JS files for no good reason at all.